# I need help identifying this cactus

Tags: cactus

I've had a bigger version of this cactus for 4 yrs now and it's about 1 meter high With very small scattered spines and has bloomed 2 times with massive pale pink flowers that open once at night and i still don't know what cactus it is. The cactus in the picture is a bit that has been knocked off that i just stuck in soil[image: this is the little bit that has been knocked off].

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a Cereus peruvianus monstrose. They usually have more spines, but the shape is right.

It looks healthy and well potted to me.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I like the plant pot it’s in as well. Looks great.